# If strings number is 0 only, hide another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So Im trying to hide the second element if the string contains a single `0`. The element should show if the number would be anything else: `10 100 11` etc. It also needs an .each function since there will be several elements with this variable in the doom.

script tried so far:

```
if ( parseInt( $('.incomingStock').html() ) > -1) $('deliverydate').css({'display':'none'})
```

HTML

```
 <div id="parent">

  <div class="incomingStock">0 i inkommande lager</div>
  <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.17</div>

  <div class="incomingStock">0 i inkommande lager</div>
  <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.17</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one 'block' with an `.incomingStock` element followed by a `.deliverydate` element?

Comment: Updated the question @Justastudent

Comment: Gave you an alternative answer, answering the looping part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to create an array from the string. Then check the index of `0` in that array & can act accordingly

```
var getText = $('.incomingStock').text().split(' '); // will create an array
if (getText.indexOf('0') >= 0){  // check if 0 is present or not
 $('.deliverydate').css({'display':'none'}) // add styles

}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bLkk9a4n/)

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you,
Here I am reading all the elements with ID = incomingStock, and then based on your condition, handling the further changes.

```
$("[id^='incomingStock']").each(function() {
        id = this.id;
        val = ($('#'+id)).val();

        if(val > -1) {
            $('deliverydate').css({'display':'none'})
        }
});
```

It would be good to help you, if you can show rough development page in which you want to use this code.

Comment: Hi! I don´t have a live page, but the elements are set in the DOM as showed, wrapped in a parent container. I can´t change from class to id (would be duplicate id´s).

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add point to selector $('deliverydate'), it must be like this - $('.deliverydate'), because it's CSS class. And why you hide element, if number is more than -1?

So probably your code must be look like that.

```js
(function($) {
  var detector = parseInt($('.incomingStock').text(), 10);
  var showElement = $('.deliverydate');
  
  showElement.hide();
  
  if (detector > -1) {
    showElement.show();
  }
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="incomingStock">0 i inkommande lager</div>
 <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.17</div>
 <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.18</div>
 <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.19</div>
```

If you need each function just because manipulated blocks is more then one, it's not. jQuery can understand multiple elements by class. (Sorry if my English is difficult for understanding).

Answer (score 0):

[brk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42898174/962603) goes into how to find the number in the element text. I want to illustrate how one can do the looping and hide every next element, as detailed in the question.

Also, I want to show how one can do the number detection differently. I am using a regular expression that checks if the number 0 as its own word is present, using a [word boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) special character.

```js
$('.incomingStock').each(function() {
  var incomingStock = $(this);
  if (incomingStock.text().match(/\b0\b/) !== null) {
    incomingStock.next('.deliverydate').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">

  <div class="incomingStock">0 i inkommande lager</div>
  <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.17</div>

  <div class="incomingStock">0 i inkommande lager</div>
  <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.17</div>
  
  <div class="incomingStock">1 i inkommande lager</div>
  <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.17</div>

  <div class="incomingStock">0 i inkommande lager</div>
  <div class="deliverydate">Leveransdatum: 2017.03.17</div>

</div>
```